# How can Android get the multiple values from the custom API using InvokeAPI method

Tags: java, android, azure

I'd like to get the customer search results from the custom API in the Azure Mobile Service. When I check the custome API using the Fiddler, it returns multiple search results. But my Invoke API only get the one result. How I can get the all results? My Azure-Mobile-Android SDK is 3.1.0

```
ListenableFuture<jsonelement> response = mClient.invokeApi("customersearch", request, JsonElement.class);

Futures.addCallback(response, new FutureCallback<jsonelement>() {
@Override
   public void onSuccess(JsonElement response) {
   Log.d("Debug","Response received!!! " + response.toString());

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {

   createAndShowDialog((Exception) throwable, "Wakeup Error");

}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KevinKo, I viewed the source code [`MobileServiceClient.java`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/blob/master/sdk/src/sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/MobileServiceClient.java), then I found the function `invokeApi` return multiple entities or only one entity via the function `Class.isArray()` for the parameter `final Class<E> clazz`.

So please use `JsonElement[].class` instead of `JsonElement.class` to try again.